# Multiplicity constraint violated - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having an issue when trying to save some data.  What I'm trying to do is, I have Orders and I have an Order that has already been fulfilled and Paid.  However, the Order Type is wrong and needs changed but in doing this it may mean VAT doesn't get added to the Order so an adjustment needs to be calculated to either give money to the Customer or have the Customer pay.  So my idea was, when an Order Type is changed on an existing Paid Order, I create a copy of the Order, so another row in the SQL database (Orders table) with the same details, create copies of the Items (Items table) that were in the Order.  However, the Order Type in the Orders table will be different.  However, when I try to do this I'm getting the error

> multiplicity constraint violated the role '_ target of the relationship has multiplicity 1 or 0..1

What happens is, the user opens the Order on screen, the Order details are retrieved from the Session and stored...

```
public void Save()
{
    App_Order form;
    List<App_Items> itemsInSession;
    ...
    try
    {
        form = (App_Order)Session["Form" + id];
        itemsInSession = (List<App_Items>)Session["FormDrugItems" + id];        
    }

    // some validation is done

    if(orderTypeChanged == true)
    {
        App_Order duplicateOrder = new App_Order();
        duplicateOrder = CreateDuplicateOrderForm(form);
        _orderService.SaveForm(duplicateOrder);
    }

}
```

..

```
public App_Order CreateDuplicateOrderForm(App_Order form)
{
    App_Order newForm = new App_Order()
    {
        OrderType = form.orderType,
        OrderDate = form.orderDate,
        CustomerId = form.customerId,
    }

    newForm.App_Items = new List<App_Items>();

    foreach(App_Items orderItem in form.App_Item)
    {
        App_Items item = new App_Items()
        {
            ItemCode = orderItem.itemCode,
            Quantity = orderItem.quantity,
            Cost = orderItem.cost
        };

        newForm.App_Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

The Multiplicity Constraint Violation mentions App_Customer has a multiplicity.  It would be a CustomerId from App_Customer that is stored in App_Order table in column CustomerId.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong or what I can do to fix it?

Thanks in advance :)

App_Order:

```
public partial class App_Order
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public App_Order()
    {
        this.App_PharmacyFormDrugItem = new HashSet<App_PharmacyFormDrugItem>();
    }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public short OrderTypeId { get; set; }
    public short OrderDate { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CustomerId_Initial { get; set; }


    public virtual Ref_OrderType Ref_OrderType { get; set; }
    public virtual Ref_PaymentMonth Ref_PaymentMonth { get; set; }

    public virtual App_Customer App_Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual App_Customer App_Customer_Initial { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<App_Item> App_Item { get; set; }

}
```

App_Customer:

```
public partial class App_Contract
{
    public App_Contract()
    {
        this.App_CustomerAddress = new HashSet<App_CustomerAddress>();
        this.App_CustomerContact = new HashSet<App_CustomerContact>();
    }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public short CustomerTypeId { get; set; }
    public short CustomerSubTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<App_CustomerAddress> App_CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<App_CustomerContact> App_CustomerContact{ get; set; }

    public virtual Ref_CustomertSubType Ref_CustomerSubType { get; set; }
    public virtual Ref_CustomerType Ref_CustomerType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<App_Order> App_Order{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<App_Order> App_Order1 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<App_Order> App_Order2 { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Would you share the App_Customer and  App_Order entities ?

Comment: Shared them above :)

Comment: Do you have any EF-DB mapping related information to share? I think that might be relevant for your issue. I have two assumptions about what might be going wrong. 
A) You reference the table App_Order several times, I don't think you can do that. You would need like 3 different foreign keys and therefore 3 different CustomerIds on the App_Order.
B) More trivial, you might have (accidentally) setup a CustomerType - App_Contract multiplicity of 0..1 - 1. If you now add the same type to several customers you would get this errors because it would be a 1:N relationship.